# Compose and Room: Issue with initializing ViewModel with a repository

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack-compose

I am currently following the [Android Room with a View codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#15) and trying to adopt it with Jetpack Compose. I am stuck in initializing the viewModel in a compose function.

The error I am getting:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:

public inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> viewModel(viewModelStoreOwner: ViewModelStoreOwner = ..., key: String? = ..., factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory? = ...): TypeVariable(VM) defined in androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose

public fun <VM : ViewModel> viewModel(modelClass: Class<TypeVariable(VM)>, viewModelStoreOwner: ViewModelStoreOwner = ..., key: String? = ..., factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory? = ...): TypeVariable(VM) defined in androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose
```

```
@Composable
fun WordBookApp() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val wordViewModel: WordViewModel by viewModel( // error here - viewModel
        WordViewModelFactory((context.applicationContext as WordsApplication).repository)
    )

    val words: List<Word> by wordViewModel.allWords.observeAsState(listOf())
    ...
```

The View Model and the View Model Factory:

```
class WordViewModel(private val repository: WordRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val allWords: LiveData<List<Word>> = repository.allWords.asLiveData()

    fun insert(word: Word) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insert(word)
    }
}

class WordViewModelFactory(private val repository: WordRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(WordViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return WordViewModel(repository) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

The other parts of the code:

```
class WordRepository(private val wordDao: WordDao) {
    val allWords: Flow<List<Word>> = wordDao.getAlphabetizedWords()

    @Suppress("RedundantSuspendModifier")
    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insert(word: Word) {
        wordDao.insert(word)
    }
}
```

```
class WordsApplication : Application() {
    private val database by lazy { WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(this) }
    val repository by lazy { WordRepository(database.wordDao()) }
}
```

```
@Database(entities = [Word::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class WordRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun wordDao(): WordDao

    companion object {
        // Singleton prevents multiple instances of database opening at the
        // same time.
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: WordRoomDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): WordRoomDatabase {
            // if the INSTANCE is not null, then return it,
            // if it is, then create the database
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    WordRoomDatabase::class.java,
                    "word_database"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                // return instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidMenifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name=".WordsApplication"
    ....
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry I think you forgot to mention the issue

Comment: Sorry for that! Added the error message now.

Comment: Well I honestly don't think the issue is with the VMs. What, HTML!?

Comment: Just copied the message! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a clue from the answer of @MARSK and fixed it. Moved the initialization of the view model to the `onCreate()` of the `MainActivity`, and passed it to the composable function. Working everything perfectly now!

Here is the code if anyone needs it in the future:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        val wordViewModel by viewModels<WordViewModel> {
            WordViewModelFactory((this.applicationContext as WordsApplication).repository)
        }

        setContent {
            WordBookApp(wordViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun WordBookApp(wordViewModel: WordViewModel) {
    val words: List<Word> by wordViewModel.allWords.observeAsState(listOf())
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you did not mention the question, I already started typing this. This may not pertain to your question, but perhaps you still should read this.

If the problem is that values are not being updated inside the viewmodel, - Initialising a viewmodel inside a composable, very bad idea.

You see the composables often recompose, where every line of code inside it is re-executed. Hence, if you initialize the viewmodel inside this composable like that, it will be re-initialised at every recomposition. Recompositions can take place theoretically even at the frame rate (even do in many cases). Hence, this is not how to declare variables inside the composable.

Ok so there's the `remember` composable to help you out with that. If you wrap the initializing statement with `remember`, it will not be re-initialised upon recompositions. However, it has its limitations. For example, if the composable gets destroyed, for example, if you swipe it off the screen, the `remember`ed value is lost. `remember` is destroyed with the destruction of the composable enclosing it.

Hence, for small stuff like animations and all, it is ok to store variables inside the composables, but for important things, you should not trust this framework.

Hence, the best way would be to initialise the viewmodel in your main activity, then pass its methods and varibales around to composables. You can even pass the viewmodel itself around, but its not required most of the time.

Code:

```
@Composable
fun WordBookApp() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val wordViewModel: WordViewModel by remember {
        viewModel( // error here - viewModel
        WordViewModelFactory((context.applicationContext as WordsApplication).repository)
    )
    }

    val words: List<Word> by wordViewModel.allWords.observeAsState(listOf())
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Learned a lot from it!!

Adding `remember` didn't resolve the issue, but got the clue! Moved the initialization of the `viewModel` in the `onCreate()` of the `MainActivity` and passed it to the composable function, and working like charm now! 

I've got my first functional Compose application with Room now! :) (Upvote for the answer!)